# Open-Source ASP.NET Analytics Framework or Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, analytics, web-analytics

I am looking for open-source ASP.NET Web Analytics framework or tools that I can customize
and add in more features in future. It has to be self-hosted. The only thing that I found 
in google search is [MotionTracker](http://motiontracker.codeplex.com/) and I am not very sure about its capability because there aren't a lot of reviews.
Thanks

Comment: Did you get any further in your research?